# Loading a web page on WebBrowser shows empty page

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, browser, webbrowser-control

I'm building a webapp on Windows Phone 7 and when i'm trying to load a certain webpage on the WebBrowser controller, all i get is the page background color and nothing else. Other pages are lodaed just fine.

On the device IE Brwoser the page showen with no problems at all.

Here is my XAML code:

```
<phone:WebBrowser IsScriptEnabled="True"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Margin="0,10,0,0"
                  Name="webBrowser"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Height="Auto"
                  Width="Auto"
                  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                  ScriptNotify="webBrowser_ScriptNotify"
                  LoadCompleted="webBrowser_LoadCompleted"/>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Well, *obviously* the problem is related to something *completely different* than your XAML.

Comment: Is it that obviouse? i'm new to WP7 and C# generally.
Do you have any idea what the problem may be?

Comment: Yes, something *completely unrelated* to all information you posted here.

Comment: well i'm not doing any special initialization to the webBrowser in my code, and due to the fact that the page is loaded correctly on the Browser application and not loaded via the controller, Do you have any helpfull information/ideas ?

Comment: Show more XAML / your navigation code. Are you using Navigate() or NavigateToString()?

Comment: @Eitan, as a general problem solving approach, especially when learning more than one thing at a time, start with something simple that works, and then add to the solution until you are meeting your needs. For now, comment out this control and any C# code-behind that needs it. Add a simple WebBrowser with Source, Height, Width, and Name properties. Set the Source="http://www.bing.com". Get that working. Then replace the Source property with C# code to Navigate to that same URL. Get that working. Repeat this process. When you get stuck, rewrite your question using what you've learned.

Comment: StackOverflow rendered that Source property to make the URL a link. I meant Source="http:// www . bing . com" without the spaced. The [WebBrowser.Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.source(v=VS.95).aspx) documentation includes a nice simple example of this sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help guys.

I figured this out.

- WebBrowser on Windows Phone 7.0 is supporting Internet Explorer 7 technologies.
- WebBrowser on Windows Phone 7.1 (7.5) is supporting Internet Explorer 9 technologies.

My project was built for Windows Phone 7.0 and on the web page were use of some jQuery API that IE 7 is not supporting.

This is the reason why the the device browser load properly the page and the `WebBrowser` controller didn't.

As soon as I changed the project to build for 7.1 the problem solved.